# Converting Arrays and Tensors in Chaquopy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, chaquopy

How do I do this?

I saw your post saying that you can just pass java Objects to Python methods but this is not working for numpy arrays and TensorFlow tensors. The following, and various variation of this, is what I tried and to no avail.

```java
double[][] anchors = new double[][]{{0.57273, 0.677385}, {1.87446, 2.06253}, {3.33843, 5.47434}, {7.88282, 3.52778}, {9.77052, 9.16828}};
PyObject anchors_ = numpy.callAttr("array", anchors);
```

I also tried to use concatenate to create this but it does not work. This is because concatenate (and stack, etc.) require a sequence containing the *names* of the arrays to be passed as an argument and there does not seem to be a way to do that with Chaquopy in Java.

Any advice?

Comment: You should include the error message in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the error you received was "ValueError: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted".

You probably also got a warning from Android Studio in the call to `numpy.array`, saying "Confusing argument 'anchors', unclear if a varargs or non-varargs call is desired". This is the source of the problem. You intended to pass one `double[][]` argument, but unfortunately Java has interpreted it as five `double[]` arguments.

Android Studio should offer you an automatic fix of casting the parameter to `Object`, i.e.:

```
numpy.callAttr("array", (Object)anchors);
```

This tells the Java compiler that you intend to pass only one argument, and `numpy.array` will then work correctly.

Comment: Error is spot on. I knew you had the answer. Much simpler than my workarounds! This also works for arrays with n dimensions! +1

Comment: I had an `ArrayList`, so I had first to use `toArray()` method on the `ArrayList` then cast as `(Object)`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find two ways that actually work in converting this toy array into proper Python arrays.

- **In Java**:

```java
import com.chaquo.python.*;

Python py = Python.getInstance();
PyObject np = py.getModule("numpy");
PyObject anchors_final = np.callAttr("array", anchors[0]);
anchors_final = np.callAttr("expand_dims", anchors_final, 0);
for (int i=1; i < anchors.length; i++){
  PyObject temp_arr = np.callAttr("expand_dims", anchors[i], 0);
  anchors_final = np.callAttr("append", anchors_final, temp_arr, 0);
}
// Then you can pass it to your Python file to do whatever
```

- **In Python** (the simpler way)

After passing the array to your Python function, using for example:

```java
import com.chaquo.python.*;

Python py = Python.getInstance();
PyObject pp = py.getModule("file_name");
PyObject output = pp.callAttr("fnc_head", anchors);
```

In your Python file, you can simply do:

```py
def fnc_head():
    anchors = [list(x) for x in anchors]
    ...
    return result
```

These were tested with 2-d arrays. Other array types would likely require modifications.