# How to Use java.cast

Tags: java, python, chaquopy

I find that there is a lack of examples of how to use a lot of these very helpful functions in https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/python.html#java.cast.

I would appreciate more examples showcasing how to perform some tasks I have struggled to perform. Such as explaining whether it is possible to convert 2-d Java arrays to Python lists, arrays, or tensors. And even just understanding what the syntax is for using java.cast().

Comment: See the comment of the accepted answer for a link to example uses in the demo app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java — and therefore in the `java` module that you link to — a "cast" doesn't actually convert an object from one runtime-type to another.<sup>1</sup> Rather, it merely converts an *expression* from one *static* type to another; and it only works if the object's runtime-type already *is* either that static type, or a subtype of it, or `null` (`None`).

That's why the `java.cast` documentation says "The object must either be assignable to the given class, or `None` (representing Java `null`), otherwise `TypeError` will be raised."

So you can't use `java.cast` to do any of the tasks you've mentioned. A Java array isn't a Python list, isn't a Python array, and isn't a Python tensor, so you can't just "cast" it to be one.

Relatedly, the documentation says that "The class must be one created by `jclass` or `jarray`, or a JNI type signature for a class or array." So there's no way to even express the idea of "cast to a Python list".

---

1. Note: Java actually has two kinds of "casts": in addition to the one for objects that I'm talking about here, there's also one for numeric primitives, whereby (for example) `((int) 3.5)` is `3`. That one really does do a value conversion, but it only applies to the seven numeric types `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`, `float`, and `double`.

Comment: Ok. It wasn't clear to me. but what I understand now is that this is only meant to convert Python classes to "Java" proxy classes that Chaquopy accepts? i would still like to see some examples to see when this can be used.

Comment: As the documentation says, the use of `cast` is is to change the "apparent type" of a Java object being accessed from Python code, since Python doesn't have a declared type on each variable. This is rarely necessary, but you can find some examples by [searching for "cast"](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/search?q=cast&unscoped_q=cast) in the demo app. As for the questioner's specific issue with 2D arrays, I'll address that in [their other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651034).

Comment: @mhsmith Yes. I ended up searching for cast in the demo app and that is what got me to understand how to use it. Hopefully, this link post will be helpful if anyone else has a similar issue!